# how to tell if a web request is coming from google's crawler?

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

From the HTTP server's perspective.

Comment: http://www.user-agents.org/index.shtml?g_m

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying Googlebot in .htaccess file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280631/verifying-googlebot-in-htaccess-file)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have captured google crawler request in my asp.net application and here's how the signature of the google crawler looks.

> **Requesting IP**: [66.249.71.113](http://www.ip2location.com/66.249.71.113)
>   **Client**: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

My logs observe many different IPs for google crawler in `66.249.71.*` range. All these IPs are geo-located at Mountain View, CA, USA.

A nice solution to check if the request is coming from Google crawler would be to verify the request to contain `Googlebot` and `http://www.google.com/bot.html`. As I said there are many IPs observed with the same requesting client, I'd not recommend to check on IPs. And may be that's where Client identity come into the picture. So go for verifying client identity.

Here's a sample code in C#.

```
    if (Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("googlebot") || 
             Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("google.com/bot.html"))
    {
        //Yes, it's google bot.
    }
    else
    {
        //No, it's something else.
    }
```

It's important to note that, any Http-client can easily fake this.

Comment: No, they're found to use wide-range of IPs all in `66.249.71.*`

Answer (score 14):

You can read the official [Verifying Googlebot](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=80553) page.

Quoting the page here:

> You can verify that a bot accessing your server really is Googlebot
> (or another Google user-agent) by using a reverse DNS lookup,
> verifying that the name is in the googlebot.com domain, and then doing
> a forward DNS lookup using that googlebot name. This is useful if
> you're concerned that spammers or other troublemakers are accessing
> your site while claiming to be Googlebot.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> > host 66.249.66.1
> 1.66.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer  crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com.
>
> > host crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com
> crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com has address 66.249.66.1
> ```
>
> Google doesn't post a public list of IP
> addresses for webmasters to whitelist. This is because these IP
> address ranges can change, causing problems for any webmasters who
> have hard coded them. The best way to identify accesses by Googlebot
> is to use the user-agent (Googlebot).

Comment: Is there no way to query google.com or googlebot.com every so often using dns to get the list of ip or ip ranges? Doing this for every incoming request seems painful. Something like an mx record for A or AAAA records.

Comment: @jjxtra I would implement this with caching.  If you only look up the IP addresses that you haven't looked up recently, it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can now perform an IP address check, by checking against googlebot's published IP address list at https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/verifying-googlebot):

> you can identify Googlebot by IP address by matching the crawler's IP address to the [list of Googlebot IP addresses](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json). For all other Google crawlers, match the crawler's IP address against the [complete list of Google IP addresses](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache Webserver, you could have a look at the log file 'log\access.log'.

Then load google's IPs from http://www.iplists.com/nw/google.txt and check whether one of the IPs is contained in your log.

Comment: nope, this is not a reliable way to do this since client IPs can change.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this. __curious_geek's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308636/956620), here's the javascript version:

```js
if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/googlebot|google\.com\/bot\.html/i)) {
  // Yes, it's google bot.
}
```

Comment: Or it's someone pretending to be a Google bot.