# Verifying Googlebot in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, googlebot

I have been investigate a bit. Will code below work? Not so easy to check.

```
RewriteEngine on
HostnameLookups Double  
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (\.googlebot\.com) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /do-something [L,R]
```

I worry the most for part

```
HostnameLookups Double
```

It says in some place that works only in httpd.confg, vps, directory(not shure what this last means if not .htaccess but not saying in htaccess).
Do you have knowledge about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition with `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^googlebot
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /do-something [L,R]
```

Though keep in mind that `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` can be spoofed.

Comment: I put above change. Do you have comment.

Comment: The part above: RewriteEngine on
HostnameLookups Double  
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (\.googlebot\.com) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /do-something [L,R]

Comment: Actually I don't know much about `HostnameLookups Double` if that is your main concern.

Comment: Anubhava I put here link for IP range question. This should be easy one for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299133/ip-range-in-htaccess-file-mor-rewite

Comment: The HTTP_USER_AGENT can be spoofed, so this isn't reliable.

Comment: Please suggest foolproof ways to detect a bot (user agent)?

Answer (score 2):

In .htaccess:

```
Order Allow, Deny

Allow from googlebot.com
Allow from search.msn.com
Allow from crawl.yahoo.net
Allow from baidu.com
Allow from yandex.ru
Allow from yandex.net
Allow from yandex.com
```

Maybe some other search engines would also be a good idea?

From Apace docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow

> ...It will do a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address to find
>   the associated hostname, and then do a forward lookup on the hostname
>   to assure that it matches the original IP address. Only if the forward
>   and reverse DNS are consistent and the hostname matches will access be
>   allowed.

Comment: Hove you tested this? How it will load `/do-something` when user-agent is `googlebot`?

Comment: Yes, it works, and Google provides this testing tool: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?vid=0-635781232591206149-2676699191&rd=2. Keep in mind that "user-agent" is easily spoofed since it's just a text string added to the HTTP request by whatever software is making the request. You can change your Chrome user agent with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg for example. The page `/do-something` will get loaded just like any public page from the perspective of the googlebot.

Comment: Question is not if it can crawl. How it will serve `/do-something` URI when user-agent is `googlebot`? Yes I know about spoofing.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand your question now. The web server is "serving", and it will do so in it's usual way if access is allowed. The user-agent is irrelevant. Does that help?

Comment: That means you didn't pay attention to what OP was trying to do. OP is trying to serve a `/do-something` URI when user-agent is `googlebot`.

Comment: Ah yes, after reading more closely I suppose you're right. I was focused on the title "Verifying Googlebot in .htaccess file". Sorry about the -1 @anubhava, and Stack Overflow won't allow me to change it unless your answer is edited... Excellent.

Comment: Oh np, we all have misunderstanding sometimes. I have edited my answer so that you can remove your downvote now.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Validate Googlebots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/5\.0\ \(compatible;\ Googlebot/2\.[01];\ \+http://www\.google\.com/bot\.html\)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} ^\*/\*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} ="gzip,deflate"
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Charset} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP:From} ="googlebot(at)googlebot.com"
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^66\.249\.(6[4-9]|7[0-9]|8[0-46-9]|9[0-5])\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^216\.239\.(3[2-9]|[45][0-9]|6[0-3])\.0
# Optional reverse-DNS-lookup replacement for IP-address check lines above
# RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^crawl(-([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){4}\.googlebot\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
# Block invalid Googlebots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Note that the optional reverse-DNS line will only work on servers which allow the use of reverse-DNS lookups.

Further, once this rDNS lookup is triggered, the format of your access log file will change; It will no longer show IP addresses as the first entry on each line, but will instead show remote hostnames. This can greatly affect your server administration process, and may cause some 'stats' programs to stop correctly reporting server access summaries. Once your server gets into this mode, it will remain that way until it is re-started.

If you have server configuration privileges, you can easily change your log file format so that it displays Remote_Addr instead of Remote_Host as the first entry on each line, regardless of whether rDNS is enabled by changing the first token in the logging format from %h to %a. See Apache mod_log_config