# IP range in .htaccess file mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this and it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /igra/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (safa|navigator) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (78\.30\.128\.0/78\.30\.159\.255)
RewriteRule ^((?!templ/).*)$ templ/$1 [L,NC]
```

I belive somwhere below is problem - somewhere IP range is it / for IP range or what?0/78 part

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (78\.30\.128\.0/78\.30\.159\.255)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use IP address range in `mod_rewrite` but you can use multiple IP starting blocks using regex OR (pipe) like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^78\.30\.(128|129)\.
```

OR this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^78\.30\.12[89]\.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to specify an IP range.

However, it might be possible to emulate a range using CIDR notation. (please note that / is actually used in CIDR notation).

So in your case, because it looks like a continuous block of IPs.. try:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 78\.30\.128\.0/24
```